# Excel vba speed optimization for importing data from excel to excel table

Tags: vba, performance, excel

Having trouble with speed of a vba script for importing data into an excel table. Hoping someone here can help. As the comments in my code state this script takes about 8 seconds to import 100 rows of data. I would love to bring it down to fractions of a second.

```
Sub ImportMyData()
    Dim filter, caption, importFileName As String
    Dim importWb As Workbook
    Dim targetSh, validationSh As Worksheet
    Dim targetTb As ListObject
    Dim importRg, targetRg, validationRg As Range
    Dim i, j, k, targetStartRow As Integer

    ' Set speed related application settings (this will be restored on exit)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Set definitions
    Set targetSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myTargetSheet")
    Set targetTb = targetSh.ListObjects("myTargetTable")
    Set targetRg = targetTb.DataBodyRange
    Set validationSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myValidationSheet")
    Set validationRg = validationSh.Range("myValidationRange")

    ' Set filter for the file choose dialog
    filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"

    ' Set UI text for file choose dialog
    caption = "Chose xlsx file to import "

    ' Set filename from UI dialog
    importFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , Caption)


    ' Show Form to get user input for extra field (will return variable 'myChoice')
    ImportFormPicker.Show

    ' Open the import file workbook
    Set importWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(importFileName)
    importWb.Windows(1).Visible = False
    targetSh.Activate

    ' Set definitions
    Set importRg = importWb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange

    ' Unprotects target sheet
    targetSh.Unprotect

    ' Get starting row of imported target range for future reference
    targetStartRow = targetTb.ListRows.Count + 1

    ' Iterate all rows in import range
    For i = 1 To importRg.Rows.Count
        ' Only import row if first cell in row is a date
        If IsDate(importRg.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            ' Count imported rows
            k = k + 1
            ' Insert row at end of target table
            targetTb.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
            ' Iterate all columns in import range
            For j = 1 To importRg.Columns.Count
                With targetRg.Cells(targetTb.ListRows.Count, j)
                    ' Import value
                    .Value = importRg.Cells(i, j).Value
                    ' Set format according to validation range
                    .NumberFormat = validationRg.Cells(2, j).NumberFormat
                End With
            Next j
            With targetRg.Cells(targetTb.ListRows.Count, j)
                ' Add custom value which was determined by user form
                .Value = Butik
                ' Set Format according to validation range
                .NumberFormat = validationRg.Cells(2, j).NumberFormat
            End With
            ' --- Speed troubleshooting = 100 rows imported/~8seconds.
            If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Activate
            End If
            ' --- End Speed troubleshooting
        End If
    Next i

    ' Close the import file workbook without saving
    importWb.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Protect target sheet
    With targetSh
        ' Protect the target sheet
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        ' Show the target sheet
        .Visible = True
        ' Activate the target sheet
        .Activate
    End With

    ' Select imported range
    targetRg.Range(Cells(targetStartRow, 1), Cells(targetTb.ListRows.Count, j)).Select

    ' Show user how many rows were imported
    MsgBox ("Imported " & k & " rows.")

    ' Restore speed related settings
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you investigated using SQL on the Excel sheet you're opening?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837414.aspx

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816562

Answer (score 0):

something like this, sorry about the variable names, did it quickly whilst on a call, you'll need to adjust

```
Sub test()

Dim q As QueryTable
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim c As New ADODB.Connection
Dim s As String

s = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\test\test_conn.xlsx;" & _
            "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
c.ConnectionString = s
c.Open

r.Open "Select * from [Sheet1$];", c, 1

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:=r, _
        Destination:=Range("Z1"))
    .Name = "Contact List"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

> AppendRangeToTable targetTb,  importRg

```
Sub AppendRangeToTable(TargetTable As ListObject, SourceRange As Range)
    Dim ar
    Dim r As Range
    ar = SourceRange.Value
    Set r = TargetTable.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True).Range
    r.Resize(UBound(ar, 1), UBound(ar, 2)) = ar
End Sub
```

I prefer CurrentRegion over UsedRange.

> Set importRg = importWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Comment: This looks great, Ill try this. But I also neet to change numberformat based on each column number. I also need to do some find and replace to fix things like spaces in numbers, incorrect decimal characters and so on. Where in the script flow should I perform these functions. I guess it would work to do these for each column.